# Meteor: How to use configure DNS with meteorhacks cluster package?

Tags: meteor, dns, load-balancing

I am using the meteorhacks:cluster package to load balance my application. https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster

I am confused about how to setup DNS entries with this package.

It seems like for each server you should provide a local env variable called CLUSTER_BALANCE_URL, which is the DNS entry for that specific server. This makes sense as I can point a DNS entry at a single server.

But what about the ROOT_URL that is set on both server. That needs to be the shared DNS entry that the user goes to. When I setup that DNS entry which server to I point it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS entries that you have pointing to your CLUSTER_BALANCE_URLs will take care of the DDP balancing.

You can have your DNS point the ROOT_URL to any server ip. There won't be a conflict. The ROOT_URL ip(s) will be the one(s) to take care of static load balancing.

https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster#dns--ssl